# Why is the akeida called - the akeida of Yitzchak (named after Yitzchak)

Tags: abraham, binding-of-isaac, yitzchak

Why is the akeida called - the "akeida of Yitzchak", after Yitzchak (and not, for example, the akeida of the son of Avraham) even though Avraham was the active one, he received the commandment and it was his experience, and it is possible that Yitzchak did not even know that he was going to be sacrificed and in fact was not active in the akeida?

Comment: "and it is possible that Yitzchak did not even know that he was going to be sacrificed" - I would have thought the binding was a bit of a give away by that point? He wasn't a kid, he was in his thirties!

Comment: famously anwered that while Avraham heard the command straight from hashem Yitzchak only heard it from avraham and therefore the test was greater (this kind of presupposes Dovs answer)

Comment: Because that's what happened?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_HaLevi_on_Torah,_Vayera.10

Comment: @אילפא, It seems that in my question I meant big ones (כיוונתי לדעת גדולים).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the term "עקידה" - "Akeida" means "binding". Whilst it was indeed Avraham's nisayon (test), practically, Yitzchak was the one who was bound.

Secondly, Yitzchak was not a child at the time - he was 37 years old (See [Rashi - Bereishis 25:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.25.20.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Seder Olam Rabbah 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=enhttps://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), as such he was able to intuit what was going on and was then fully aware and submitted himself to both his father and G-d.

According to the Midrash - [Bereishis Rabbah 56:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.56.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the binding was a request that came straight from Yitzchak as he was worried that if he would move, he might render the sacrifice invalid:

> דָּבָר אַחֵר, אָמַר רַבִּי יִצְחָק בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁבִּקֵּשׁ אַבְרָהָם לַעֲקֹד יִצְחָק בְּנוֹ, אָמַר לוֹ אַבָּא בָּחוּר אֲנִי וְחוֹשֵׁשַׁנִי שֶׁמָּא יִזְדַּעֲזַע גּוּפִי מִפַּחֲדָהּ שֶׁל סַכִּין וַאֲצַעֲרֶךָ, וְשֶׁמָּא תִּפָּסֵל הַשְּׁחִיטָה וְלֹא תַעֲלֶה לְךָ לְקָרְבָּן, אֶלָּא כָּפְתֵנִי יָפֶה יָפֶה, מִיָּד וַיַּעֲקֹד אֶת יִצְחָק, כְּלוּם
>
> Another matter, Rabbi Yitzcḥak said: When Avraham sought to bind Yitzchak his son, he (Yitzchak) said to him (Avraham): ‘Father, I am a young man, and I am concerned that my body will tremble due to fear of the knife, and I will [thereby] upset you, or perhaps the slaughter will [thereby] be rendered unfit and it will not be counted for you as a valid offering. Therefore, bind me very well.’ Thereupon, “he bound Isaac his son.”